# Non equilibrium black hole radiating away energy and angular momentum, with total energy and angular momentum conserved

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, black-holes, gravitational-waves, black-hole-thermodynamics

The question refers to whether mass (i.e., energy) and angular momentum can be considered to have been carried away by the gravitational radiation in the hole settling down. And whether those entities are conserved by the combination of black hole and gravitational wave. Ashtekar et al (2003, 2011) claim that dynamical horizons can be defined as having a mass and angular momentum assigned to it, in fact calculated locally by metric properties only on that horizon (and thus not needing to know the whole global metric), in a canonical way. They also state that the outermost or some specific dynamical horizon (multiple ones can exist) are, through their construction, defined covariantly. And the difference between before and after is exactly the mass and angular momentum in the Bondi-Sachs covariant definition of the radiation flux at null infinity.

I could not follow whether you can really define the covariant dynamical horizons. I do know that Bondi and Sachs were indeed covariant.

Is there a consensus on this, for asymptotIcally flat spacetimes? Or any counter-arguments?

Comment: Have you looked for any empirical results on energy, momentum and angular momentum conservation in systems with strong gravity? Those are the only "arguments" that matter in physics.

Comment: @CuriousOne seems that LIGO either found or assumed that energy conservation. 65 original solar masses , 3 in grav radiation an d 62 left. 62 plus 3 is 65. Does that matter in physics? And since grav waves had not been seen but only predicted theoretically before 2015 does that mean they didn't matter before 2015? All the efforts by more than a thousand to build LIGO didn't matter? Or was it the theory that made those people build it what did not matter? Your comment is philosophical, not physical.

Comment: But my question was about the dynamical process. Can we study and predict with those assumptions? Does the math show that or not? It was a question.

Comment: LIGO does measurements on the strongest gravity scenarios that are available to us. The instrument is agnostic about energy etc. conservation. The models that we fit to the data can be conservative (plain vanilla GR) or assume mechanisms that break these conservation laws. If we were to see deviations from the GR model outputs, then we would have to consider other, possibly non-conservative models. If the LIGO data does not fit to the GR models, there should be plenty of buzz soon. As to the chances of LIGO finding new clues about gravity... I wouldn't bet on that scenario, but that's OK.

Comment: LIGO has a multiplicity of functions. It doesn't just validate what we think we know about gravity. It is, first and foremost, an astronomical telescope. With LIGO we can count the statistics of such mergers and we can analyze their characteristics (like relative masses and types of partners). That is, as far as I know, not possible with other instruments. We can also use the LIGO signals as triggers for x-ray and gamma ray searches to get more data about these events and to study the complex physics of mergers. None of that is impacted by GR being already the correct (aka "boring") theory.

Comment: My question was not beyond General Relativity, but within. Ashtejar's papers are within GR. It just consider the dynamic evolution phase that in strong gravity is not done analytically, and treated investigates the dynamical process, claimed to be covariantly. It talks about the dynamical evolution to no hair. Dynamical horizons have not had as much visibility as stationary or slightly perturbed event or apparent horizons. ELISA will do more to get into the more detailed structure of the evolution becUuse of the longer interferometer arms. Still plenty to research in old boring (not my term)GR

Comment: As an experimentalist I would frame it this way: LIGO's prediction about the distance of the detected sources depends on the numerical models about the total mass-defect being correct. So if the predictions are wrong because of a poor understanding of the mechanisms within GR, then the sources would be at a different distance than predicted, is that right? I would completely agree that this may be a great test of how well we understand GR, if, indeed, we don't understand it (well enough), yet. Thankfully, that's for the theorists to ponder. :-)

Comment: No, it's not distance. It will see multipole radiation consistent with no hair or not. It's not distance but spectroscopy, it'llsee the wave patterns, frequencies and phases. Distance only affects the amplitude. By the way, Ashtekar is a well known Geneal Relativity researcher, no woo there. Yes, this and other theoretical calculations from 'theorists'' (I call them and experimentalists and phenomenologists physicist)

Comment: So the prediction for total radiated power stays the same, it's just the different orders in the multipole expansion that are uncertain? OK. I take that.

Comment: Right. So is there an answer?

Comment: I certainly can't answer that. The folks who are fitting the models will have to look at it and write a paper about the possibility to distinguish the models. Personally I wouldn't take any such fits awfully seriously until there is more and, most importantly, more precise data available. Whether the current generation of gravitational wave detectors can tease these things out will have to be seen.